# What is wrong with my classList .add function?

Tags: javascript, foreach, navbar, addition, addeventlistener

I'm making video slider background but my *Javacript for video slider navigation* doesn't work (when i click on the button, the video doesn't change). The console announces mistake as "*Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
at sliderNav*" . I don't know what's wrong...anybody knows please help me! Thạn you so much!

This is my html and JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Website Landing Page - With Background Video Slider | Travel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <a href="#" class="brand">Travel</a>
        <div class="menu-btn "></div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="navigation-items">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Explore</a>
                <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="home">
        <video class="video-slide" src="vid3.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
        <video class="video-slide" src="vid2.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
        <video class="video-slide" src="vid1.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
        <video class="video-slide" src="vid4.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>

        <div class="content active">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Camping.<br><span>Enjoy</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Adventures.<br><span>Off Road</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Road Trip.<br><span>Together</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Feel Nature.<br><span>Relax</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-icons">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-navigation">
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn')
        const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation')

        menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                menuBtn.classList.toggle('active')
                navigation.classList.toggle('active')
            })
            ////Javacript for video slider navigation
        const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-btn')
        const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.video-slide')

        var sliderNav = function(manual) {
            btns.forEach((btn) => {
                btn.classList.remove('active')
            })
            slides.forEach((slide) => {
                slide.classList.remove('active')
            })

            btns[manual].classList.add("active")
            slides[manual].classList.add("active")
        }

        btns.forEach((btn, i) => {
            btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                sliderNav(i)
            })
        })
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

This is my css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

header {
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 200px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

header .brand {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header .navigation {
    position: relative;
}

header .navigation .navigation-items a {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 30px;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

header .navigation .navigation-items a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

header .navigation .navigation-items a:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}

section {
    padding: 100px 200px;
}

.home {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #ED2CC4;
}

.home:before {
    z-index: 777;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(3, 96, 251, 0.3);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.home .content {
    z-index: 888;
    color: #fff;
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: none;
}

.home .content.active {
    display: block;
}

.home .content h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    line-height: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.home .content h1 span {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.home .content p {
    margin-bottom: 65px;
}

.home .content a {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    color: #1680AC;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.home .media-icons {
    z-index: 888;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.home .media-icons a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.home .media-icons a:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.home .media-icons a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.home video {
    z-index: 000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.slider-navigation {
    z-index: 888;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateY(80px);
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn.active {
    background: #2696E9;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.slider-navigation .nav-btn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.video-slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    clip-path: circle(150% at 0 50%);
}

.video-slide.active {
    clip-path: circle(150% at 0 50%);
    transition: 2s ease;
    transition-property: clip-path;
}

@media (max-width: 1040px) {
    header {
        padding: 12px 20px;
    }
    section {
        padding: 100px 20px;
    }
    .home .media-icons {
        right: 15px;
    }
    header .navigation {
        display: none;
    }
    header .navigation.active {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
    }
    header .navigation .navigation-items a {
        color: #222;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    header .navigation .navigation-items a:before {
        background: #222;
        height: 5px;
    }
    header .navigation.active .navigation-items {
        background: #fff;
        width: 600px;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 40px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgb(1 1 1 / 20%);
    }
    .menu-btn {
        background: url(menu.png)no-repeat;
        background-size: 30px;
        background-position: center;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }
    .menu-btn.active {
        z-index: 999;
        background: url(close.png)no-repeat;
        background-size: 25px;
        background-position: center;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 560px) {
    .home .content h1 {
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 60px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `btns` array holds five elements while your `slides` array only holds four elements so when clicking on the last button you access slides[4], which is undefined.

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-btn')
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.video-slide')
```

You need to add another video element or remove a button from your page:

```
<video class="video-slide" src="vid3.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
<video class="video-slide" src="vid2.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
<video class="video-slide" src="vid1.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
<video class="video-slide" src="vid4.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>

<div class="slider-navigation">
     <div class="nav-btn"></div>
     <div class="nav-btn"></div>
     <div class="nav-btn"></div>
     <div class="nav-btn"></div>
     <div class="nav-btn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yah i remove one nav-btn but one video sits still , it doesn't change to another video...there's no mistake on the console this time